# CSV file label encoded

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file that has (0,1,77,99) unique values for a column which are somehow encoded for (yes, no, don't know, missing). How can I make sure which value stand for which word?

Comment: I would say 0->No, 1->Yes, 77->don't know and 99-> missing because that make sense for me :)

Comment: "How can I make sure which value stand for which word" Aside from reasoning about it, you can't

Comment: Yes, I understand (I would say 0->No, 1->Yes, 77->don't know and 99-> missing because that make sense for me :)) but there are many other such analogies I am not able to understand. CSV link:- https://wmwhymnh.labs.coursera.org/notebooks/assignments/assignment2/assets/NISPUF17.csv

Comment: Your csv is not freely downloadable.